# How to exclude pom.xml from bitbucket auto merge in git

Tags: git, maven, bitbucket

We have bitbucket backed by git repository for version control. We have different release-wise branches for each unique Java project, which is a jar file eventually. For ex, branches are named as R1, R2, R3 etc. Changes done in R1 should merge to R2 and R3. We made use of auto-merge option available, and it is working fine and doing an auto-merge to all upstream branches.

However, the pom.xml version (for ex: JAR1-SNAPSHOT.001) change in R1 branch also merged to upstreams, thereby creating duplicate jars in our artifactory.

Wondering if there is a way to exclude only pom.xml for auto merge?